# A Markov Chain Question

Tags: markov-chains

Problem I am working on is as follows ;

*Suppose that whenever the Washington Wizards win a game, they will also
win the next one with probability 0.75 and lose it with probability 0.25. However, if
the team loses a game, then they win the next one with probability 0.40 and lose it
with probability 0.60. The consecutive results obtained by the team is a Markov chain.*

One of the questions asks the following;

*If the team is scheduled to play 82 games during the season, what is
the expected overall record of wins vs. losses?*

What I have done so far?

1) Created the transition matrix (State 0: Losing the match, State 1: winning the match) $$
      T = \begin{bmatrix}
        0.60 & 0.4\\
        0.25 & 0.75\\
        \end{bmatrix} $$

2) Found the steady-state probabilities using steady-state equations ;

$$
\pi_0\ = 5/13
$$
$$
\pi_1\ = 8/13
$$

3) Assumed that team will earn 1 point if it wins a game (and 0 if it loses) and for a single game

$$\sum_{i=0}^1 c(i)*\pi_i\ = (1)*8/13 + (0)*5/13 = 8/13
$$

So does it make sense to multiply this result with 82, to come up with 82 games' expected overall record of wins vs losses?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, your thoughts are right. The expected value is approximately $50.46$ winning games out of 82 played games. And $31.54$ expected loosing games.